# How to get the ssl certificate information from a webview?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, chromium

I can't seem to find any documentation on this for webviews. Is there a way to get the ssl certificate information from a webview?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function for that, neither through the Browser API or Electron. But you can get the certificate through node.js in the main process. For example by using the 'https' module.

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
    hostname: 'nodejs.org', 
    agent: false, 
    ciphers: "ALL",
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};    

new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
    https.get(options, function (res) {
        var certificate = res.socket.getPeerCertificate();
        if(typeof (certificate) === 'undefined' || certificate === null) {
            reject({message: 'The website did not provide a certificate'});
        } else {
            resolve(certificate);
        }
    });
}).then(function(certificate) {
    console.log(certificate)
});
```